# Why does my Terminal command line screw up like this? (bash's fault?)

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, history

When I use the command line history ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> )

The command line screws up like this:
[image]

The cursor is supposedly located at the end of the line ( just pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> )

If I press enter, just `source ~/.bash_profile` is executed, the rest is just rubbish on the screen.
Although it works as it should, I'd like the terminal to not  be visually broken.

edit:
This is my PS1:
`PS1="\033[0;31m[mac] \033[0;37m\w\033[1;36m> \033[1;0m"`

Comment: Your PS1 *seems* fine. Set it as mine and used command line history to bring up `source ~/bash_profile` as you described and it worked without issues, but I'm bad at reading those escape sequences manually, so there still could be an issue there that just didn't take effect due to other differences in out setups.

Answer (score 8):

It's most likely an issue with what you've set your PS1 to in your .bashrc or .bash_profile.  Specifically, I'd expect it's related to incorrect escape sequences.

Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706750/why-is-this-bash-prompt-acting-strangely-disappearing-and-how-do-i-fix-it-os-x) with more information.  It's hard to tell exactly without seeing what your PS1 is set to.

Comment: Oh that's probably it. I updated the question with my PS1. Although the colors show correctly, the escape sequences may be wrong.